# Android - Know if app already running

Tags: android, device, lifecycle

My application has 2 different possible launch scenarios : standalone or launched by another app (with specific intent).

If launched in standalone mode after it is launched by another app, my app is completely broken (I deal with bluetooth, etc).

Is there any way to know when my app is launched from another app whether or not my standalone app is already running on the device?

Comment: May be you can use onReume(). Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658687/how-to-use-onresume

Comment: I think this link might help your situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched