# Can't call a method from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Basically i need to call a method, which refreshes the username in my NavigationBar. I try to call it from another activity `SettingsActivity.java`, where the user changes his name.

SettingsActivity.java:

```
// ...
MainActivity tempActivity = new MainActivity();
tempActivity.refreshNBName();
// ...
```

When i do this i get this exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference`

I've tried to do this another way:

```
((MainActivity)getApplicationContext()).refreshNBName();
```

But this throws another exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.justnothing.nisser.debbie.GlobalVariables cannot be cast to com.justnothing.nisser.debbie.MainActivity`

The method that i'm trying to call here looks like this:

```
public void refreshNBName(){
    NavigationView nV = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headerView = nV.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView local_user = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.actualUser);

    local_user.setText(((GlobalVariables) getApplication()).name + " " + ((GlobalVariables) getApplication()).surname);
}
```

What should i do here? Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind)

Comment: Activities are particular object that are not supposed to be instatiate unsing new. So your tempActivty object is not correctly instantiate and will surely contain field not initialized. So it failed

Comment: So what can I do here to fix the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't  you store the username in shared preferences or pass username when you start main activity using putExtra()

Comment: The problem is not that i cannot get the username, it is that i need to update the shown name in my NavBar using `refreshNBName()`

Comment: See updated answer dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote this which is not applicable.

```
MainActivity tempActivity = new MainActivity();
tempActivity.refreshNBName();
```

**Because** this is creating new instance of MainActivity class. not referring to the live instance of MainActivity.

You tried another thing, you can't even do this.

```
((MainActivity)getApplicationContext()).refreshNBName();
```

**Because** `getApplicationContext` will return you context of [application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)  class which is not MainActivity.

I have gone through your question, you need not call any method from another activity. If you want update navigation drawer. You can call `refreshNBName()` on [onResume()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658687/how-to-use-onresume) of `MainActivity.class`.
So every time user comes back to MainActivity, navigation view will update automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, everything works like a charm!

Comment: Welcome, please study android + java tutorials. You need to be strong in basics if you want to be a great developer.

Answer (score -1):

You can create static method in MainActivity  and than call the method like this MainActivity.someMethod() but i don't recommend this ! it can lead to memory leak and lots of exception to handle

if your main activity is not alive and is in the pause,stop,destory state there is no point to refreshing the view in main activity and you can always refresh the view to latest data when activity state changed to resume by overwriting onResume method in activity  .

and finally i think best way to communicating with activates and fragment is using callback  for more information see this link :

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot make the method static: "Non-static method 'findViewById(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context"